# TypeError when chaining generic functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic function that converts an object to a string, and I wanted to make that function chainable:

```js
interface ChainableToStringFunction<T> {
  (instance: T): string;
  then: (another: ChainableToStringFunction<T>) => ChainableToStringFunction<T>;
}
```

When I use this function on an array of objects in combination with the `map` function, Typescript can correctly determine the type:

```js
interface DummyType {
  name: string;
}
const dummies: DummyType[] = [{name: "John"}, {name: "Lucy"}];

//It works with a single chainable. Typescript can correctly derive the type
console.log(dummies.map(asChainable((dummy) => dummy.name)));//Logs ["John", "Lucy"]
```

However, when I chain 2 functions, I get a type error, stating that the type of `dummy` is Unknown:

```js
dummies.map(asChainable((dummy) => dummy.name)
              .then(asChainable((dummy) => dummy.name))
)
```

and to fix it, I need to use

```js
dummies.map(asChainable<DummyType>((dummy) => dummy.name).then(asChainable((dummy) => dummy.name)))
```

Note the additional `<DummyType>`.

My question is whether I can avoid having to specify this additional `<DummyType>` by either:

- Adjusting the interface definition
- Adjusting the `asChainable` function

The full code, including the type error (or view/run it on [the Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-J5LVSxXCOhgOcqEu-rtmAobINAORFFoOhrvayDEDAc7mlayB-sgDANiAxA1iAG5ktuvZ7ge7KIb6-rnpe17YneQgPk+JFWq+cAuvIbw6CAlG3veSGPpU9GWoxzHvp+kQVmAxAUgAHlBK6geB9a4VuO6EYeCzHqe5FXgkVFsEGVo2vanBccGdEvm+rG6Bx2o4jR3EmdxAmHEJbJAA)):

```js
interface ChainableToStringFunction<T> {
  (instance: T): string;
  then: (another: ChainableToStringFunction<T>) => ChainableToStringFunction<T>;
}

function asChainable<T>(
  stringProducer: (instance: T) => string
): ChainableToStringFunction<T> {
  let chainable = function (instance: T): string {
    return stringProducer(instance);
  } as ChainableToStringFunction<T>;
  chainable.then = function (anotherChainable: ChainableToStringFunction<T>): ChainableToStringFunction<T> {
    return asChainable((instance) => {
      const firstString = stringProducer(instance);
      return `${firstString}-${anotherChainable(instance)}`;
    });
  };
  return chainable;
}

interface DummyType {
  name: string;
}
const dummies: DummyType[] = [{name: "John"}, {name: "Lucy"}];

//It works with a single chainable. Typescript can correctly derive the type
console.log(
    dummies.map(asChainable((dummy) => dummy.name))
);

//This gives a type error: the type of dummy is unknown
console.log(
    dummies.map(asChainable((dummy) => dummy.name).then(asChainable((dummy) => dummy.name)))
);

//to fix the type error
console.log(
    dummies.map(asChainable<DummyType>((dummy) => dummy.name).then(asChainable((dummy) => dummy.name)))
);
```

Comment: I can't quite figure out what's going on here, but note that your first example will break as well if you write it as `console.log(dummies.map(dummy=>asChainable((dummy) => dummy.name)));`.  I'm not sure why that is but maybe it will help someone else sort it out.